# Spring 4 spring:url htmlEscape attribute missing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Have anybody experienced situation when migrating to Spring 4.0.2 `htmlEscape` attribute from `<spring:url>` tag is missing.

Have you any suggestin how to fix this.
My error:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag.setHtmlEscape`

It seems to my that I added all needed spring dependencies.

Comment: Try deleting your work and temp folder

Comment: I have cleaned whole project, made maven rebuild and problem still occurs.
I also checked spring classes to find out if there is not `setHtmlEscape` but it is present